# How do I use ffplay to play a list of audio files

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

There are many audio and video players but I prefer to use one tool for many purposes. And so I thought of using `ffplay` as both audio and video player.

To play a file the command is like this.

```bash
ffplay path_to_audio_file.mp3
```

***Fine, but how do I play a list of audio files or a list of videos?***

I tried to use:

```
ffplay *.mp3
```

but to no avail. It gives me the following error:

```
Argument 'audiofileB.mp3'  provided as input filename, but 'audiofileA.mp3' was already specified.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ffplay` appears to only support a single input file, so you'll need to use code to loop over a list of input files (and possibly to shuffle them); wildly assuming `coreutils` (for `shuf`), perhaps something like:

```
find musicdir -type f -name "*.mp3" | shuf | while read f; do ffplay -autoexit -- "$f"; done
```

This will of course break horribly if there are spaces or newlines in the filenames.

(My current music player is fairly similar, `find ~/music -type f -name "*.mp3" | mpg123 --shuffle -Z --list -`)

Comment: I tried you solution and it's almost good, but ... there are some problems related to ffplay which I'm not sure if they should be resolved in this question or in another. one of problems is that ffplay will not end playing current song and for this reason will not go to the next song at the end of current untill I will not use CTRL+c keyboard combination.

Comment: @Scantlight the `-autoexit` flag seems relevant to that issue.

Comment: `-autoexit` solved that issue. Now I have another which can be solved by using `-nodisp` ... this will disable the visualisation of waveform and similar stuff. This will avoid to create a new window and steal focus from current working application (this was very annoying behavior). would you like to include this option in your answer, as a possible option to solve the annoying behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I found from this https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068478

```
for f in *.mp3 ; do ffplay -autoexit "$f"; done
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is basically a duplicate of [thrig’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275257/80216#275263):```while read f; do ffplay -autoexit -- "$f"; done```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't read it to the end.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread while I was writing an FFplay GUI in Lazarus/FPC. It could already play a dropped file list and skip to next/previous file, but I had to kill the ffmpeg process and create a new one every time. I was trying to add the ability to play a whole file list. The simplest workaround I found to the moment was of course using -autoexit, and creating a playlist file with this Pascal code:

```
begin
      AssignFile(tfOut, C_FNAME);
      try
        rewrite(tfOut);
        for i:= 0 to Fichiers.Items.Count - 1 do
        if Fichiers.Selected[i] then
        begin
          writeln(tfOut, 'file ' + #39 + conv(Fichiers.Items[i]) + #39)
        end;
        CloseFile(tfOut);
      except
        on E: EInOutError do
        ShowMessage ('File error')
      end;
  end;
```

Then reading it this way:

```
'ffplay -f concat -safe 0 -i flist.txt -autoexit'
```

which is the same syntax I use for concatenating files with FFMPeg.

I'm now searching for a proper way to add a delay if files are image files…

Answer (score 1):

`ffplay` can use the concat demuxer similar to `ffmpeg`.

Create a file that lists up the files you want to play:

```
# list.txt
file 'audiofileA.mp3'
file 'audiofileB.mp3'
```

Then run ffplay:

```
ffplay -f concat -i list.txt
```

Other useful options:

- Use `-autoexit` to make it exit when it's done
- Use `-loop 0` to loop forever (press <kbd>q</kbd> to quit).
- Use `-safe 0` if the file paths are absolute (or contain other special characters).

See the ffmpeg wiki about [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) for more details.